# How to use a css file from a different folder

Tags: html, css

How to do I link my files in sub-folder which is located in root folder.

For example : I created a file in a separate folder with name **example1/assests/css/style.css**.

I created a new folder **example1/example2** and now I want to use the style.css file in my tool.php file which is located in **example2** folder.

How do I do this ?

Comment: Use a relative path like `../assets/css/style.css`

Comment: or (../assests/css/style.css) , if you have not made a typo in your question

Comment: Please show what you have in your tool.php.  This has nothing to do with php, it's an html issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way relative references work is fairly simple. The basics that you need to understand for this are the uses of `.`, `..`, and `/`.

A single dot (`.`) means the current directory. If you had style.css in the same subdirectory as tool.php you would use `./style.css`

Your problem, however, will be solved with a double-dot (`..`). Double-dot stands for the parent directory (aka up one level in your path). Since the **example2** directory and the **assets** directory share the same parent (**example1**), you can use the double-dot to "hop up" to the **example1** directory and then follow the path to **style.css**. Your path should look something like: `../assets/css/style.css`

The forward slash signifies something *within* something else. `folder/document` means the file titled "document" within the "folder" directory. `./file` would be the file "file" within the current directory.

Hope this helps  : )